# Can't bind to '(ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' in angular unit test case

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I got "Can't bind to '(ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'" error in angular unit test case

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    template: `<form>
                <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel]="modelValue"/>
               </form>`
})

class TestFormComponent {
    modelValue: 'xyz';
}

describe('TestFormComponent', () => {
    let component: TestFormComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestFormComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ FormsModule ],
            declarations: [ TestFormComponent ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be ok', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
            const el = input.nativeElement;

            expect(el.value).toBe('xyz');

            el.value = 'abc';
            el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

            expect(component.modelValue).toBe('abc');
        });
    }));
});
```

Error

TestFormComponent should update model value FAILED
        Error: Template parse errors:
        Can't bind to '(ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
                        ][(ngModel]="modelValue"/>
                       ")

I have imported FormsModule. Please guide me if anything i missed out

Comment: did the answer help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template is wrong

change from

```
 <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel]="modelValue"/>
```

to

```
 <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="modelValue"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajee also i got test fail in this `expect(el.value).toBe('xyz')` stmt. i have set the initial value like modelValue: 'xyz'. Why its not working?

Comment: i have no idea on test, i will have a look and update you